# Call dll function from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2017, call, dllimport

I have CAD dll it's called **plclient_kompas.dll**. This is a library for standard machinebuilding parts.

In **plclient_kompas.dll** contains function **PLInsert3D**, that puts standard part from library to 3D assembly.

In manual to this library said that:

```
HRESULT **PLInsert3D**(
[in] IPARTLibProvider* aPLClient;
[in] IBOResponseDisp* aMethodResponse;
[in] ksPlacement* aPlacement;
[out, retval] IDispatch** result);
```

So I want to call this function from vs2017 vb.net code like this:

```
<DllImport("C:\Program Files\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D v17\Libs\PARTLib\Clients\plclient_kompas.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>

Public Shared Function **PLInsert3D**(aPLClient As IPARTLibProvider, aMethodResponse As BOResponse, aPlacement As ksPlacement) As ksPart

End Function 


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

iMainPart = **PLInsert3D**(aPLClient, aMethodResponse, aPlacement)

End Sub
```

But in this line:

```
iMainPart = **PLInsert3D**(aPLClient, aMethodResponse, aPlacement)
```

I have error access violation exception.

What I do wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Addition what I wrote.
This is my code in vb.net:

```
Imports Kompas6API5
Imports KompasAPI7
Imports PARTLibClient
Imports BOSimple
Imports Kompas6Constants3D
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports stdole

Public Class Form1
    
    <DllImport("C:\Program Files\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D v17\Libs\PARTLib\Clients\plclient_kompas.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function PLInsert3D(ByRef aPLClient As IPARTLibProvider, ByRef aMethodResponse As BOResponse, ByRef aPlacement As ksPlacement) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> ksPart
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim kompas As Object
        Dim ksdoc As Object

        kompas = New Kompas6API5.Application

        kompas.Visible = True

        ksdoc = kompas.Document3D
        ksdoc.Create(False, False)

        ksdoc.Filename = "C:\Users\Baha1990\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Kompas3D\3d files\1.a3d"
        ksdoc.UpdateDocumentParam
        ksdoc.Save

        Dim aPLClient As BOSimpleProvider
        aPLClient = New PARTLibClient.BOSimpleProvider

        Dim Location As String
        Dim Response As Object
        Location = ""
        Response = aPLClient.SelectEx(0, 0, Location, 0)

        Dim aMethodResponse As BOResponse
        aMethodResponse = aPLClient.GetMethod(Location, "КОМПАС 3D")

        Dim iDoc3D As ksDocument3D
        Dim iMainPart As ksPart
        Dim aPlacement As ksPlacement
        
        iDoc3D = kompas.ActiveDocument3D

        iMainPart = iDoc3D.GetPart(-1)
              
        aPlacement = iMainPart.GetPlacement
        aPlacement.SetOrigin(0, 0, 0)

        iMainPart = PLInsert3D(aPLClient, aMethodResponse, aPlacement)

    End Sub
```

This is a sample from API manual in C#:

```
// Тестовая библиотека вставки объекта в КОМПАС из СИ
/*
 * Необходимо у подключаемых библиотек BOSimple и PARTLibClient выставить значение параметра
 * Embed Interop Types = False
 *
 * */
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using KAPITypes;
using Kompas6Constants;
using Kompas6API5;
using Kompas6API7;
using PARTLibClient;
using BOSimple;
using Kompas6Constants3D;
using stdole;

using System.Runtime.Versioning;

namespace PartLibAPI

{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class InsertKompas
    {
        const string _LIBRARYNAME = "Вставка изделия в Компас из СИ";
        const string _KEYNAME = @"SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{";
        const string _KOMPASLIBRARY = "Kompas_Library";
        const string _DLLPATH = "plclient_kompas.dll";
        const string _KERNEL32 = "kernel32.dll";

        #region Методы для работы библиотеки в Компас

        private KompasObject _kompas;
        // Название библиотеки
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string GetLibraryName()
        {
            return _LIBRARYNAME;
        }

        // Головная функция библиотеки

        public void ExternalRunCommand([In] short command, [In] short mode, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object kompas_)
        {
            _kompas = (KompasObject)kompas_;
            switch (command)
            {
                case 1:
                    InsertInKompas(_kompas);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Функция получения меню
        // Описание функции можно найти в SDK API Компас
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string ExternalMenuItem(short number, ref short itemType, ref short command)
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            itemType = 1; // "MENUITEM"
            switch (number)
            {
                case 1:
                    result = "Вставить";
                    command = 1;
                    break;
                //
                // Для корректной работы библиотеки необходимо добавить конец меню (или подменю)
                //
                case 2:
                    command = -1;
                    itemType = 3; // "ENDMENU"
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }
        #endregion

        // Делегаты для работы с методами из plclient_kompas.dll
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private delegate int _PLInsert2D(IPARTLibProvider aPLClient, IBOResponse aMethodResponse, double aX, double aY, double aAngle);
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private delegate void _PLInsert3D([Out] out IDispatch retVal, IPARTLibProvider aPLClient, IBOResponse aMethodResponse, ksPlacement aPlacement);
        private void InsertInKompas(KompasObject kompas)
        {
            // Подключаемся к plclient_kompas.dll (получаем ссылку на запущенный экземпляр в процессе Компаса)
            IntPtr pDll = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                pDll = LoadLibrary(_DLLPATH);
                if (pDll == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Exception("Не могу найти plclient_kompas.dll");
                // Получаем адреса экспортируемых функций из ранее загруженной plclient_kompas.dll
                var pProc2D = GetProcAddress(pDll, "PLInsert2D");
                var pProc3D = GetProcAddress(pDll, "PLInsert3D");

                // Получаем экземпляры делегатов, приведенных к соответствующему типу
                var PLInsert2D = (_PLInsert2D)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc2D, typeof(_PLInsert2D));
                var PLInsert3D = (_PLInsert3D)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc3D, typeof(_PLInsert3D));

                IApplication kompasApp = kompas.ksGetApplication7();
                if (kompasApp == null)
                    throw new Exception("Не удалось получить указатель на интерфейс приложения!");
                var doc2D = (Document2D)kompas.ActiveDocument2D();
                var doc3D = (Document3D)kompas.ActiveDocument3D();
                if ((doc2D == null) && (doc3D == null))
                    throw new Exception("Откройте документ или создайте новый!");
                // Подключаемся к API справочника
                IPARTLibProvider PLClient = null;
                try
                {
                    PLClient = new BOSimpleProvider();
                    var errorMsg = String.Empty; 
                    // Подключаемся к серверу приложений
                    if (PLClient.Connect(ref errorMsg) == 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // Получаем доступ к изделиям и папкам в справочнике
                            var commonData = PLClient.CreateCommonDataObj();
                            commonData.InitUserData();
                            string plm2D = "2D"; // Документ 2D
                            string plm3D = "Solid3D"; // Документ 3D

                            // Типы документов Компаса

                            string[] methodNames = { "", "КОМПАС 2D", "КОМПАС 2D", "КОМПАС 3D", "КОМПАС 3D", "КОМПАС 3D", "" };
                            string[] docName = { "?", plm2D, plm2D, plm3D, plm3D, plm3D, "?" };

                            // Получаем тип документа

                            var docType = GetDocType(kompasApp);

                            ksPart mainPart = null;

                            ksPart pPart = null;

                            ksPlacement partPlace = null;

                            if (docType == DocumentTypeEnum.ksDocumentAssembly)

                            {

                                if (doc3D != null)

                                {

                                    mainPart = doc3D.GetPart((short)Part_Type.pTop_Part);

                                    if (mainPart != null)

                                    {

                                        pPart = doc3D.GetPart(0);

                                        partPlace = pPart != null ? pPart.GetPlacement() : mainPart.GetPlacement();

                                 }

                               }

                           }

                            // Задаем режим работы справочника в зависимости от типа активного документа в КОМПАС

                            commonData.SetFindOptions(docName[(int)docType]);

                            // Путь до корневого каталога с ISO стандартами по уникальному ID

                            var ISOFolder = commonData.FolderByID("A259_151417DFF6474BF6");

                            // Просматриваем каталог в глубину

                            while (ISOFolder.FolderCollection().Count() > 0)

                            {

                                ISOFolder = ISOFolder.FolderCollection().Folder(0);

                                // В случае если в каталоге есть хотя бы один класс

                                if (ISOFolder.ClassCollection().Count() > 0)

                                {

                                    // Получаем указатель на интерфейс первой типоразмерной таблицы его изделий

                                    var ISOClass = ISOFolder.ClassCollection().plClass(0);

                                    var instance = ISOClass.Instances("", docName[(int)docType]);

                                    var paramGrid = instance.ParamGrid(0);                                  

                                    // Просматриваем типоразмерную таблицу сверху-вниз

                                    for (int i = 0; i < paramGrid.PGRowCount(); i++)

                                    {

                                        // Выбираем строку

                                        paramGrid.SelectRow(i);

                                        // Получаем полный location получившегося изделия

                                        var location = instance.plPart().GetLocation(0);

                                        // Получаем метод для вставки изделия в зависимости от типа активного документа

                                        var methodResponce = PLClient.GetMethod(location, methodNames[(int)docType]);


                                        // Вставляем изделие в КОМПАС

                                        var X = 5 * i * Math.Sin(15 * Math.PI * i / 180);

                                        var Y = 5 * i * Math.Cos(15 * Math.PI * i / 180);

                                        var Angle = 180 - i * 15;

                                        IDispatch kPart;

                                        switch (docType)

                                        {

                                            case DocumentTypeEnum.ksDocumentAssembly:

                                                // Задаем место в сборке

                                                partPlace.SetOrigin(X, Y, 0);

                                                PLInsert3D(out kPart, PLClient, methodResponce, partPlace);

                                                break;

                                            case DocumentTypeEnum.ksDocumentDrawing:

                                                PLInsert2D(PLClient, methodResponce, X, Y, Angle);

                                                break;

                                            case DocumentTypeEnum.ksDocumentFragment:

                                                PLInsert2D(PLClient, methodResponce, X, Y, Angle);

                                                break;

                                            case DocumentTypeEnum.ksDocumentSpecification:

                                                PLInsert3D(out kPart, PLClient, methodResponce, null);

                                                break;

                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)

                        {

                            kompas.ksMessage(ex.Message);

                        }

                        finally

                        {

                            // Отключаемся от сервера приложений

                            PLClient.Disconnect();

                        }

                    }

                    else

                        kompas.ksMessage("Ошибка подключения к серверу приложений: " + errorMsg);

                }

                catch (Exception ex)

                {

                    kompas.ksMessage("Ошибка! Не удалось создать COM-объект." + ex.Message);

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                kompas.ksMessage(ex.Message);

            }

            finally

            {

                // Освобождаем загруженную plclient_kompas.dll

                FreeLibrary(pDll);

            }

        }

 
        /// <summary>

        /// Метод определения типа документа

        /// </summary>

        /// <param name="kompasApp"></param>

        /// <returns></returns>

        private DocumentTypeEnum GetDocType(IApplication kompasApp)

        {

            return kompasApp.ActiveDocument == null ? DocumentTypeEnum.ksDocumentUnknown : kompasApp.ActiveDocument.DocumentType;

        }

        // Импортируем в проект методы из kernel32.dll для подключения к plclient_kompas.dll

        [DllImport(_KERNEL32, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]

        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Process)]

        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libFilename);

        [DllImport(_KERNEL32, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]

        static internal extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr HModule, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr), In] string funcName/*lpcstr*/);

        [DllImport(_KERNEL32, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]

        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Process)]

        public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

        #region COM Registration

        // Эта функция выполняется при регистрации класса для COM

        // Она добавляет в ветку реестра компонента раздел Kompas_Library,

        // который сигнализирует о том, что класс является приложением Компас,

        // а также заменяет имя InprocServer32 на полное, с указанием пути.

        // Все это делается для того, чтобы иметь возможность подключить

        // библиотеку на вкладке ActiveX.

        [ComRegisterFunction]

        public static void RegisterKompasLib(Type t)

        {

            RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine;

            try

            {

                var keyName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", _KEYNAME, t.GUID.ToString(), "}");

                regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(keyName, true);

                regKey.CreateSubKey(_KOMPASLIBRARY);

                regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", true);

                regKey.SetValue(null, System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\mscoree.dll");

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("При регистрации класса для COM-Interop произошла ошибка:\n{0}", ex));

            }

            finally

            {

                regKey.Close();

            }

        }

        // Эта функция удаляет раздел Kompas_Library из реестра

        [ComUnregisterFunction]

        public static void UnregisterKompasLib(Type t)

        {

            RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine;

            var keyName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", _KEYNAME, t.GUID.ToString(), "}");

            RegistryKey subKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(keyName, true);

            try

            {

                subKey.DeleteSubKey(_KOMPASLIBRARY);

            }

            finally { subKey.Close(); }

        }

        #endregion

    }

}
```

Comment: Try using `CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl` instead.

Comment: There's loads of the detail missing here. Most notable all of the type declarations. There's also more to calling a function that getting the types right. That's just syntax. You also have to pass valid arguments, not just arguments of the correct type.

Comment: @Nick Abbot Used CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl instead the problem is same.

Comment: You have an IDispatch retrun type there, so you could add, on the method, `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]` and get an `object` back that you then cast to the Interface.

Comment: ...but, since this VB.Net, I'm not sure `[return:...]` is supported, so you'll have to add it to the return type of the function (as, IIRC, `(...) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> type`).

Comment: @Jimi                                                                                        
 Like this?:                                                                                        <DllImport("C:\Program Files\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D v17\Libs\PARTLib\Clients\plclient_kompas.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>                                            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]

Public Shared Function **PLInsert3D**(aPLClient As IPARTLibProvider, aMethodResponse As BOResponse, aPlacement As ksPlacement) As ksPart
End Function

Comment: Nope, `[return: ...]` is the C# *version* (I realized it was VB.Net too late :). The second comment (e.g., `(...) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> ksPart`). From the documentation, you should know to what Interface you need to cast. -- This is what I would try to do, anyway (unless you use some form of late-binding there).

Comment: @Jimi Ok I did like this:                                                                               
 `Public Shared Function PLInsert3D(aPLClient As IPARTLibProvider, aMethodResponse As BOResponse, aPlacement As ksPlacement) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> ksPart`                      But it still throws acces violation exception.

Comment: Guessing: Is iMainPart initialized to something? Not nothing? `iMainPart = new ksPart` We have to narrow down whether the access violation is in the input params or iMainPart.

Comment: @NickAbbot  `iMainPart` is interface of 3d CAD assembly where I want to place a part from library `plclient_kompas.dll`. So I cannot write `iMainPart = new ksPart` because ksPart interface doesnt support this word `new`.

Comment: @NickAbbot So I want to somehow join `iMainPart`(3D CAD assembly interface) and function `PLInsert3D` from library `plclient_kompas.dll` and hope that standard part from library will appear in my 3d assembly.

Comment: We cannot see what objects / Interfaces you're using, how you're using them, whether the declarations are correct or, actually, anything else. Building a test code is also probably quite difficult.

Comment: @Jimi Let's presume that I am using Interfaces/objects right, I have doubt only in call of function from dll, because I am not a programmer and first time encounter function call, I want to gather more information about this topic, if you have any suggestion that will help approach to my aim I am glad to hear you. I have API manual for this language but it's in russian, and there are samples in c#, c++, and Delphi are given. For non programmer it's seemed that in vb.net is easier to write a code. And I wil be glad to any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Posting the C# example could be a good idea, these two languages (VB.Net and C#) are almost identical.

Comment: "Let's presume that I am using Interfaces/objects right," Let's not. That's just a waste of our time.

Comment: @Jimi I edited my question and added full listing my code in vb.net and sample from API manual in C#.

Comment: That looks like something that's meant to be called through COM (items of note are the `HRESULT` and the `[in]` and `[out, retval]` and `IDispatch`).  As such, you should not expect to be able to use `DllImport` to call it.  I'm not sure, though, what the correct incantations are.  Most of the comments above appear to be misled into trying to make the `DllImport` work.

Comment: @Craig I don't think so, because plclient_kompas.dll is native or unmanaged coded I could not to reference this library in visual studio 2017. I think `dllimport` is right way to call function `PLinsert3D`, but I must somehow Marshal [out, retval] IDispatch in my managed code, I don't know how exactly.

Comment: You're right, even though it's a very COM signature, the C# code is calling it through LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress.  Have you considered just translating the C# example to VB?  It doesn't look like it's doing anything that VB can't do.

Comment: @Craig I ve tried, but could not to translate this from c# to vb.net: `IDispatch kPart; PLInsert3D(out kPart, PLClient, methodResponce, partPlace);`

Comment: I would have thought the problem would come earlier.  Those two lines are just `Dim kPart As IDispatch` and `PLInsert3D(kPart, PLClient, methodResponce, partPlace)` (the `out` is something required in C# but not in VB).

Comment: @Craig Do you mean in this line there is no need to code `[out, retval] IDispatch` in vb.net: `private delegate void _PLInsert3D([Out] out IDispatch retVal, IPARTLibProvider aPLClient, IBOResponse aMethodResponse, ksPlacement aPlacement);` and write sth like: `private delegate sub _PLInsert3D(IPARTLibProvider aPLClient, IBOResponse aMethodResponse, ksPlacement aPlacement);`?

Comment: You would still need the IDispatch member in the parameter list, you just wouldn't include an `out` token in front of it---VB doesn't have any support for `out` beyond general `ByRef` parameter support to my knowledge, and unlike C#, does not require flagging such parameters.